# Do both ascertain and determine mean the same here?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

> The challenge facing public health officials is to anticipate an outbreak of disease and then ----- that school children are immunized.

Both words have to be in present tense, obviously. But determine here will sound odd. I knew people used "determined" as in "I determined that next year would be my lucky year". Most of time, determine is followed by "whether".

But here ascertain makes more sense and would mean to make sure.

Comment: Actually, "determine" carries more of a sense of "make sure" than "ascertain".  But if "make sure" is what you mean, that's what you should say, as neither "ascertain" nor "determine" strongly implies "make sure" -- their primary sense is "measure the degree to which" or something of that ilk.

Comment: The question should be closed as unclear. Just what does the OP mean here by "mean the same"? They are clearly different words, with slightly different meanings in general, let alone in this sentence. How similar or different do their meanings need to be, for the OP to be satisfied that they do or do not mean the same thing?

Comment: The thing here is I never heard anyone said "to determine that". Usually heard "determine whether".

Comment: "Determine whether" is preferred over "determine that" -- 7:1 on the Ngram viewer and 5:1 in the web google, but the disfavored locution still gets millions of hits.

Answer (score 2):

Neither is correct in your example sentence. The right word in your context is *ensure*.

> The challenge facing public health officials is to anticipate an outbreak of disease and then ensure that school children are immunized.

To ascertain means to find out, and to determine means to arrive at a conclusion.